# How to show image for each li with text properly

Tags: html, css

How do I show li text with an image properly? I have an image in each li, with text . The text is coming under image but I want to change the text appearance, so that is not wrapped under the image. How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/skofdc9L/2/

```
    <ul>
    <li>
    <img src="http://dropbox.smallparade.com/bigbubble.png" width="24" height="24"> This is thetextfdhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfhd</br>fhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfh. 
    </li>
    <li>
    <img src="http://dropbox.smallparade.com/bigbubble.png" width="24" height="24"> This is the LI textTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTes</br>tTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest. 
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you want to show it on top of the image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :

```css
li {
display:flex;
align-items : center;
}

img {
margin-right : 15px;
align-self : flex-start
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Starsinthesky.jpg/1920px-Starsinthesky.jpg" width="24" height="24"> This is thetextfdhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfhd</br>fhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfh.
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Starsinthesky.jpg/1920px-Starsinthesky.jpg" width="24" height="24"> This is the LI textTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTes</br>tTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But image is coming center of the li..i want to show top like top zero

Comment: @cinnan then add this to your image `align-self : flex-start`

Answer (score 0):

try this code i play with `width calc`.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
li span{
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  display :inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
    <img src="http://dropbox.smallparade.com/bigbubble.png" width="24" height="24"> 
    <span>This is thetextfdhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfhd</br>fhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfhdfh. </span>
    </li>
     <li>
    <img src="http://dropbox.smallparade.com/bigbubble.png" width="24" height="24"> 
    <span>This is the LI textTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTes</br>tTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest. </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```